# Use Filter To Search In Options add a null option in angularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I Have a problem with filter in AngularJS . i use filter to show options based Input From Search Box . everything works but  every time i search(except default option (Set with `ng-model`)) it adds a null option in results .

i set `ng-model`  for `<select>` tag

here is my Code

```
<div class="choosePatternHeader">
    <span>Pattern name</span>
    <input ng-model="obj.name" type="text">

</div>
<div class="select_div">
    <select  size="4"  ng-model="pattern" ng-options="p.name  for p in patterns | filter:obj">
    </select>
</div>
```

here is result when i search "pattern 4"

```
<select class="ng-pristine ng-valid" ng-options="p.name for p in patterns | filter:obj"    ng-model="pattern" size="4">
<option value="?" selected="selected"></option>
<option value="0">pattern 4</option>
</select>
```

and result when i search "pattern 1" (default option)

```
 <select class="ng-pristine ng-valid" ng-options="p.name for p in patterns | filter:obj"    ng-model="pattern" size="4">
<option value="0">pattern 1</option>
</select>
```

here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WmbRR/)

Answer (score 1):

The same happens with `<option ng-repeat="p in patterns">`, so I guess that's the underlying problem.

The only "solution" I have found is to simply make use of the empty value by defining an empty option, e.g. `<option value="">Please select</option>`.

Comment: tnx you . i have created an issue on Git of AngularJS

Answer (score 1):

I solved as follows

```
function MyController($scope, $filter)
{
    $scope.patterns=[{name:'pattern 1'},{name:'pattern 2'},{name:'pattern 3'},{name:'pattern 4'}];
    $scope.pattern=$scope.patterns[0];

    $scope.$watch('obj.name', function(value){
          var filtered_devices = $filter('filter')($scope.patterns, {name:$scope.obj.name});         
          if (filtered_devices) {
              $scope.pattern = filtered_devices[0];
          }
    }, true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS will indeed add a dummy option if `ng-model` is set to a value that is not in `ng-options`. I am not aware of a way to prevent this when the filter doesn't return any values (when `ng-options` is empty, `ng-model` can never be in it), but when it does, you could set `ng-model` to the first item, which means the dummy option will not be created. You could use `ng-change` or similar to do this.

Comment: i add ng-model . try my jsFiddle link . everything work untill when i insert a string in searchbox to filter the data